# Make the boundary of markers more apparent in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I use pgfplots to draw a black-white array resembling `imshow()` in MATLAB.

I use the following code (from [Plot a matrix of real values with TikZ/PGF like imshow in matlab](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8238/plot-a-matrix-of-real-values-with-tikz-pgf-like-imshow-in-matlab) ) to do it

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
    \begin{axis}[x=4mm,y=4mm,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,colormap={bw}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}]
    \addplot[scatter,scatter src=explicit,
             only marks, mark=square*,mark size=2mm]
             table[x=x,y=y,meta=l] {datafile.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But if the blocks are all black, the boundary line between them disappears. I want the boundary line to be more apparent. How can I do that?

I have problem posing image, see

[image]

for an example.

Comment: Could you include an example of what your datafile looks like?

Comment: Do you want the line to be white, or gray, or some other colour?

Comment: @Jake Do you think it's time we close this one?

Comment: @percusse: Yes, I think so. There'd be too much speculation required for an answer, and if anyone needs this later on, they can just ask a new question.

Comment: @Jake Voted as TL.