# Create a 3D figure (surf) from .csv file

Tags: pgfplots

I have a .csv file with 3 columns: time, f and psd. I would like to create a 3D surf plot using this data. Just like the following image generated in Matlab. [image].

Here is the link to the data I am trying to use: [datastft.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1eztcujtknses88/datastft.csv?dl=0).

The code that I am using is the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3 [surf] table[x=time, y=f, z=psd, col sep=comma] {datastft.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Using this code I am getting this image with lines:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This compiles for me, after changing from `sep` to `col sep`, and adding the missing semicolon at the end of the `\addplot` line.

Comment: Hi @TorbjørnT., Thank you so much. It worked now! Now I need help to make the plot pretier, because the plot is made of lines. Do you know how can I achieve an aspect just like the Matlab figure above?

Comment: No, not really. I suggest you edit your question with the updated code and describe what is wrong with the output.

Comment: You should leave a blank line in your .csv file each time the x-coordinate (in your case "time") changes value.

Comment: Please add `datastft.csv` directly to your question and do not link them to a cloud solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pgfplots` does not know, how the data are organized. There are thirteen scan lines. Either separate the blocks with empty lines in the `.csv` file or count them and specify them: `mesh=rows=13`.

Package `pgfplots` provides many different shaders and patch types (see library `patchplots`.

Some examples:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x dir=reverse]
\addplot3 [surf, mesh/rows=13, shader=interp]
  table[x=f, y=time, z=psd, col sep=comma] {datastft.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result interp]

With `shader=faceted interp`:

> [image: Result faceted interp]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x dir=reverse]
\addplot3 [surf, mesh/rows=13, shader=interp, patch type=bilinear]
  table[x=f, y=time, z=psd, col sep=comma] {datastft.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result interp/patch type=bilinear]

Comment: I am trying this example but it shows an error that `\package{filecontents}` not found

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/211703)

Comment: @supriya The line `\usepackage{filecontents}` comes from the example of the question. But is is not needed and I have it removed in the updated answer. BTW, if a package is not found, installing it would be the usual option.