# Pgfplot 3Dsurface from CSV

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have already read [Create a 3D figure (surf) from .csv file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250762/create-a-3d-figure-surf-from-csv-file), [2D surface on a 3D surface plot external data in a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103023/2d-surface-on-a-3d-surface-plot-external-data-in-a-file) but nothing seems to work.

I have the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3 [surf, mesh/rows=1000, shader=interp] table[col sep=comma] {Results_CSV/F6/F6_TTF_adaptaAndskillAndWeightModif.csv};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With the following data: [data](https://pastebin.com/WZN5hSTv). When I compile, I get the following error:

```latex
! Package pgfplots Error: CRITICAL: shader=interp: got unsupported pdf shading 
type '0'. This may corrupt your pdf!.
```

Which I don't understand. I have indicated the number of rows, so it should be OK right?
Thanks a lot for the help.

edit: there are 4 columns per row in the data file as I would like to plot row 1, 2 and 3 as a 3d surface and use row 4 as a color, to represent the 4th dimension.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, what are you trying to plot here, I see 4 dimensions for a 3d plot, could you detail a more please.

Comment: Yes of course. I would like to plot the row 1, 2 and 3 as a surface and use the row 4 as a color, to represent the 4th dimension.

Comment: Yup I have read this one, but it does not seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data format regarding how you section your matrix into.

Therefore, I assumed that you matrix has 10 rows and the result is that each rows has 100 elements. Please note that the `mesh/rows` definition is not the same as the number of rows in your `.csv`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf,  mesh/rows=100,   shader = interp]
    table[x=a, y=b, z=c, col sep = comma] {fem.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this will give you

[image]

**TLDR:** The data is not input in the right-way. If you segment your data properly and enter it properly you should get what you want `:)`

> Disclaimer: I did not use the color info from you file.